# Code works, but not desired output, need help debugging (Java) [New programmer :D]

Tags: java, output, text-files

Create a console application that will read the content of two files (employees.txt and managers.txt).

The application should store information about department using Map data structure.

Following class should be created:

-An Employee class with information first name, last name and salary (monthly);

-A Manager class with information about first name, last name, salary (monthly) and yearly bonus (as a percent of wages)

Use inheritance for creating classes.

Output following reports into separate files:

-Average salary per department, example Marketing 1000, Production 2000;

-The total amount of money needed to pay all the salaries in the department;

-All managers yearly bonus amount

-The highest salary for the employee per department* and their names

-The lowest salary for the employee per department* and their names

*There can be one or more employees with the highest salary

*There can be one or more employees with the lowest salary

Note: There can be more than one manager per department

One of the **outputs** are wrong, it's supposed to say:

> The person with the highest salary in Marketing is: John Prodigy

But instead I get:

> The people with the highest salary in Marketing are: John Prodigy and Pasty Laprade

Here's my *attempt* at the code:

*Note: scp = scanner production, scm = scanner marketing, hsp = highest salary production, lsp = lowest salary production, hsm = highest salary marketing, lsm = lowest salary marketing, salPro = salary production, salMar = salary marketing, emp = employees*

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuBarUI;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scp = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\denim\\IdeaProjects\\ProgrammingAssignment\\src\\com\\company\\employees.txt"));
        Scanner scm = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\denim\\IdeaProjects\\ProgrammingAssignment\\src\\com\\company\\managers.txt"));
        int salPro = 0;
        int salMar = 0;
        ArrayList<Employee> marketing = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Employee> production = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> emp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        while(scp.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] obj = scp.nextLine().split(", ");
            switch(obj[2]) {
                case "Production": {
                    salPro += Integer.parseInt(obj[3]);
                    Employee e = new Employee(obj);
                    production.add(e);
                    if (emp.containsKey("hsp")) {
                        if (production.get(emp.get("hsp")).getSalary() < Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.replace("hsp", (production.size()-1));
                        else if (production.get(emp.get("hsp")).getSalary() == Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.put("hsp1", (production.size()-1));
                    }
                    else {
                        emp.put("hsp", (production.size()-1));
                    }
                    if(emp.containsKey("lsp")) {
                        if (production.get(emp.get("lsp")).getSalary() > Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.replace("lsp", (production.size()-1));
                        else if (production.get(emp.get("lsp")).getSalary() == Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.put("lsp1", (production.size()-1));
                    }
                    else {
                        emp.put("lsp", (production.size()-1));
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "Marketing": {
                    salMar += Integer.parseInt(obj[3]);
                    Employee e = new Employee(obj);
                    marketing.add(e);
                    if (emp.containsKey("hsm")) {
                        if (marketing.get(emp.get("hsm")).getSalary() < Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.replace("hsm", (marketing.size()-1));
                        else if (marketing.get(emp.get("hsm")).getSalary() == Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.put("hsm1", (marketing.size()-1));
                    }
                    else {
                        emp.put("hsm", (marketing.size()-1));
                    }
                    if(emp.containsKey("lsm")) {
                        if (marketing.get(emp.get("lsm")).getSalary() > Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.replace("lsm", (marketing.size()-1));
                        else if (marketing.get(emp.get("lsm")).getSalary() == Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.put("lsm1", (marketing.size()-1));
                    }
                    else {
                        emp.put("lsm", (marketing.size()-1));
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        while(scm.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] obj = scm.nextLine().split(", ");
            switch (obj[0]) {
                case "Production": {
                    salPro += Integer.parseInt(obj[3]);
                    Manager m = new Manager(obj);
                    production.add(m);
                    if (emp.containsKey("hsp")) {
                        if (production.get(emp.get("hsp")).getSalary() < Integer.parseInt(obj[3]))
                            emp.replace("hsp", (production.size() - 1));
                        else if (production.get(emp.get("hsp")).getSalary() == Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.put("hsp1", (production.size()-1));
                    } else {
                        emp.put("hsp", (production.size() - 1));
                    }
                    if (emp.containsKey("lsp")) {
                        if (production.get(emp.get("lsp")).getSalary() > Integer.parseInt(obj[3]))
                            emp.replace("lsp", (production.size() - 1));
                        else if (production.get(emp.get("lsp")).getSalary() == Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.put("lsp1", (production.size()-1));
                    } else {
                        emp.put("lsp", (production.size() - 1));
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "Marketing": {
                    salMar += Integer.parseInt(obj[3]);
                    Manager m = new Manager(obj);
                    marketing.add(m);
                    if (emp.containsKey("hsm")) {
                        if (marketing.get(emp.get("hsm")).getSalary() < Integer.parseInt(obj[3]))
                            emp.replace("hsm", (marketing.size() - 1));
                        else if (marketing.get(emp.get("hsm")).getSalary() == Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.put("hsm1", (marketing.size()-1));
                    } else {
                        emp.put("hsm", (marketing.size() - 1));
                    }
                    if (emp.containsKey("lsm")) {
                        if (marketing.get(emp.get("lsm")).getSalary() > Integer.parseInt(obj[3]))
                            emp.replace("lsm", (marketing.size() - 1));
                        else if (marketing.get(emp.get("lsm")).getSalary() == Integer.parseInt(obj[3])) emp.put("lsm1", (marketing.size()-1));
                    } else {
                        emp.put("lsm", (marketing.size() - 1));
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The total Salary of the Production Department is: " + salPro);
        System.out.println("The total amount of Employees in the Production Department is: " + production.size());
        System.out.println("The Average Salary for the Production Department is: " + salPro/(production.size()));

        System.out.println("\nThe total Salary of the Marketing Department is: " + salMar);
        System.out.println("The total amount of Employees in the Marketing Department is: " + marketing.size());
        System.out.println("The Average Salary for the Marketing Department is: " + salMar/(marketing.size()));

        if(emp.containsKey("hsp1")) System.out.println("\nThe people with the highest salary in Production are: " + production.get(emp.get("hsp")).getFullName() + " and " + production.get(emp.get("hsp1")).getFullName());
        else System.out.println("\nThe person with the highest salary in Production is: " + production.get(emp.get("hsp")).getFullName()) ;
        if(emp.containsKey("lsp1")) System.out.println("The people with the lowest salary in Production are: " + production.get(emp.get("lsp")).getFullName() + " and " + production.get(emp.get("lsp1")).getFullName());
        else System.out.println("The person with the lowest salary in Production is: " + production.get(emp.get("lsp")).getFullName()) ;

        if(emp.containsKey("hsm1")) System.out.println("\nThe people with the highest salary in Marketing are: " + marketing.get(emp.get("hsm")).getFullName() + " and " + marketing.get(emp.get("hsm1")).getFullName());
        else System.out.println("\nThe person with the highest salary in Marketing is: " + marketing.get(emp.get("hsm")).getFullName()) ;
        if(emp.containsKey("lsm1")) System.out.println("The people with the lowest salary in Marketing are: " + marketing.get(emp.get("lsm")).getFullName() + " and " + marketing.get(emp.get("lsm1")).getFullName());
        else System.out.println("The person with the lowest salary in Marketing is: " + marketing.get(emp.get("lsm")).getFullName()) ;

    }
}
```

Here are the **classes** that I made

```
package com.company;

public class Manager extends Employee {
    private int Bonus;

    public Manager(String department, String firstName, String lastName, int Salary, int Bonus) {
        super(firstName, lastName, department, Salary);
        this.Bonus = Bonus;
    }

    public Manager(String[] list) {
        this(list[0], list[1], list[2], Integer.parseInt(list[3]), Integer.parseInt(list[4]));
    }

    public int getBonus() {
        return Bonus;
    }
}
```

```
package com.company;

public class Employee extends Person {
    private int Salary;
    private String department;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String department, int Salary) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.department = department;
        this.Salary = Salary;
    }

    public Employee(String[] list) {
        this(list[0], list[1], list[2], Integer.parseInt(list[3]));
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return Salary;
    }
}
```

```
package com.company;

public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Here's the **text files** (managers.txt and employees.txt)

```
Marketing, John, Prodigy, 5300, 15
Production, Boss, Old, 2000, 20
Production, Bossic, Young, 1400, 20
```

```
Ginny, Gullatt, Marketing, 1000
Tiara, Curd, Production, 1200
Camie, Poorman, Marketing, 900
Jammie, Hasson, Marketing, 800
Lionel, Hailey, Marketing, 500
Genevive, Mckell, Production, 2000
Esteban, Slaubaugh, Marketing, 1300
Elden, Harte, Production, 1340
Tasia, Rodrigue, Marketing, 1200
Nathanial, Dentler, Production, 1700
Valda, Nicoletti, Marketing, 600
Kary, Wilkerson, Production, 600
Coletta, Akey, Marketing, 800
Wilmer, Jack, Production, 600
Loreta, Agnew, Marketing, 700
Suzy, Cleveland, Production, 1450
Pasty, Laprade, Marketing, 1300
Candie, Mehaffey, Production, 1800
Glady, Landman, Marketing, 1900
Tierra, Mckeown, Production, 2200
```

Comment: And please choose a proper title, you obviously appended stuff to the title because just "Code works, but not desired output" was not allowed.

Comment: Your code would also be much easier to read if you would assign `obj[x]` from your scan to actual, meaningful variables.

Comment: Sorry, added the meaning of the variables right before the code.

Comment: Solved myself, thanks for looking tho :D!

Comment: No, they all need to be *in* the code, if your code needs a manual then you did something seriously wrong. Use your IDE to refactor all the names and magic strings.

Answer (score -1):

Despite the fact that the code is 'working', it does not fulfill the described requirements:

- It does not use a `Map` structure to maintain its data at runtime. Instead, the data is stored in two `ArrayLists` and the `Map` is merely used as a 'jump table', remembering the indices of certain employees to aid processing specific values.
- The reports regarding total and highest/lowest salary must be outputted to files instead of the console. This is, however, not related to the problem discussed in the question.
- A condition is that there can be 'one or more employees' with a highest/lowest salary. The code only deals with the special cases of 'one or two employees'.

---

For the `Map` part, the author of the assignment is likely trying to guide you with this restriction. For now, you got some code that is close to solving the problem and it is obvious to tell that you ended up duplicating large sections due to the fact that you are dealing with two departments in two files.

At this point we want reduce this logic in a way that a single section of code is capable of finding the desired salary values and employees, regardless of department. How could a `Map` help with that?

---

What I like about the code are the convenient constructors, such as

```
public Employee(String[] list) {
    this(list[0], list[1], list[2], Integer.parseInt(list[3]));
}
```

In larger programs this logic should not be tied to a class designated for holding business data, but for now it is perfectly fine. It allows to quickly use the logic of an `Employee` wherever needed.

```
String[] input = ...
Employee fromInput = new Employee(input);
System.out.println("Hi, I'm " + fromInput.getFullName() + ", currently working at ...");
```

However, through the majority of the program you are using the `String[] obj` that was parsed during the input, which is partially responsible for the code obscurity some commenters already pointed out.

In java, object references are very light-weight, hence the third line in the following code sample has minimal impact on performance

```
Employee cursor = ...
if(cursor.getSalary() > ...) {
    Employee theOneWithHighestSalary = cursor;
    // do something with it
}
```

Consequently, try to retrofit the code to use instances of `Employee` wherever possible. Firstly for readability, but also for extensibility later on.

---

Last but not least, the primarily described error results of improper invalidation.

Currently, the code is capable of finding one or two employees with a highest/lowest salary. If, at any point in the algorithm, only one such employee is known, it is referred to as `hsp`/`lsp`, etc. If another employee with an equal salary is found, that one is referred to as `hsp1`, etc.

However, if yet another employee is found to have a salary higher than `hsp`, only the information regarding `hsp` is updated and `hsp1` remains as is, falsely referring to an employee with a lower salary. Instead, the information about `hsp1` must be cleared at this point.